# Cannot install luasql using luarocks

Tags: mysql, lua, luasql

I'm having a problem installing luasql using luarocks. As I understand, I need to do it in command prompt. I already  did the necessary preparations:

1. I  installed lua 5.1 because I need this version.
2. I installed luarocks and mysql.
3. I also added in the environment variables the location of luarocks.bat.
4. I found the location of mysql.h
5. I found the location of libmysql.dll

WHen I type the following in command promt:

***luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1"  MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\lib"***

, I have the following error:

***The system cannot find the path specified.***

What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try create `c:\external` dir. and put mysql.lib file in `lib` folder and `*.h` files in `includede` folder. This is default search paths for LuaRocks.

Comment: Hello. When I typed luarocks in cmd, it also said the "system cannot find specified path".

Comment: Does it have something to do with the config-5.3.lua installed?